# Can node.js send a file / folder to recycle bin (trash on MacOS) instead of fs.unlink / fs.rmdir?

Tags: node.js

I couldn't find any info regarding this question.

Is there even a way for **node.js** to send a file / folder to bin instead of fs.unlink / fs.rmdir?

### For example:

Can you do something like `sendToBin(path)` to send a file to **recycle bin** (Windows) **trash** (MacOS) instead of running `fs.unlink()` to remove file from disk (I know that it just marks it with 0)

Comment: Please explain your question in more detail.

Comment: @zero298 I mean. That's all there is to explain. can you do something like `fs.sendToBin(path)` instead of  `fs.unlink(path)`?

Comment: `bin` means `Trash` ?

Comment: What is `fs.sendToBin()` supposed to do?

Comment: @MukeshSharma yeah, the recycle bin (Windows)

Comment: I edited the question, sorry if it wasn't clear

Comment: try this https://github.com/sindresorhus/trash

Comment: @MukeshSharma thank you! I didn't realized that Google doesn't know what "recycle bin" means, usually it's very good with synonyms. If you replace the word **bin** for **trash** all of the sudden you can find the node modules...

Comment: If you are using electron.js, there is [shell.trashItem()](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/shell#shelltrashitempath)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Node.js`'s `fs` doesn't provide any api for moving files to `Trash`/`Recycle Bin`, but you can try [trash](https://github.com/sindresorhus/trash) node-module to have work-around.

Comment: Thanks, now at least 1 result will pop up when you search **"node.js send file to bin instead of deleting from disk permanently"** in Google. Literally spent 10 minutes trying to find anything, turns out I had to use the word "trash" (MacOS) instead of "bin" (Windows)

Answer (score 0):

**Updated 2024:**
You can use `shell.trashItem(path)` for moving files to `Trash/Recycle Bin`

```
const { shell } = require('electron')
shell.trashItem(path)
```