# Is there a javascript function to move a file to trash instead of delete it directly from disk?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

Now the function `OS.File.remove (file)` was used, where `file` is the path, for example `d:/files/aa.txt`, however the file was removed directly from disk. Is there a function to move the file to the trash (Windows or Linux)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can node.js send a file / folder to recycle bin (trash on MacOS) instead of fs.unlink / fs.rmdir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50350097/can-node-js-send-a-file-folder-to-recycle-bin-trash-on-macos-instead-of-fs-u)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK , the there is no native API for this.
There are 3rd party solutions like this which you can make use of -
https://github.com/sindresorhus/trash